# Showing associated records in a index table - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

I am building a wholesale order app and I need help creating an index page table that shows multiple associated records.

Within a index table I would like to show order id, customer name (this is the field I’m struggling with) and total value of order.

How do I show the contact name (Contact.name) for each record within the index table?

Here are my models, the order controller and the order index view:

**Order Model**

```
has_many :cart_contacts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :contacts, through: :cart_contacts

def customer_id
  #This is the method I’m currently trying to use to display the record 
end

def total_price
  line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
end
```

**Cart_contact Model**

```
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to :contact, optional: true
belongs_to :order, optional: true
```

**Contact Model**

```
has_many :cart_contacts
has_many :orders, through: :cart_contacts
```

**Orders Controller**

```
def index
  @orders = Order.all
end
```

**Order Index View**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= order.id %> </td>
        <td> <%= order.customer_id %> </td>
        <td> <%= number_to_currency(order.total_price) %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I feel like I could be doing a couple of things wrong here.

Comment: Is the customer a table in your db?

Comment: How is the customer and order table related? R u mentioning the contact as a customer?

Comment: Yes, so the Customer is a contact and Contact has_many Cart_Contacts and the association is Orders has_many :contacts, through: :cart_contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Order` model should have an association with customer through 
`belongs_to :customer` which is mapped to `customer_id` already. So two things here:

- if the association exists your are overriding the `customer_id` with your method
- if the association doesn't exist, you need to add it (field and association)

In both cases you have to delete the function `customer_id`.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, please add the following

```
def customer_id
self.cart_contacts.joins("LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = cart_contacts.contact_id").select("contacts.name")
end
```

This will return an array of contacts names associated with the order. Hope contact_id and order_id is present in the cart_contacts table.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is along the right track, however this is what is returned: "#<CartContact::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fc8e03aa8f8>" and not the name. How can I get this to return "Name"?

Comment: What are the attributes in cart_contacts table?

Comment: The attributes in the cart_contact table are: contact_id, order_id & cart_id.